# MapReduce job never enters in running state

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have small jar file which is correct because i tested it on other computer and it works with hadoop.

Now i have setup hadoop on my pc and when i submit a job then it never passes the accept state.

In the browser i can see that the job is accepted but it never gets executed. Here is the screenshot.
[image]

I see there is a warning in the console:

```
WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
```

Full logs are :

```
   C:\Users\afraz\Desktop\MapReduceData>hadoop jar outs.jar 1902 spo
2019-05-01 22:27:40,842 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2019-05-01 22:27:41,882 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2019-05-01 22:27:41,925 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/afraz/.staging/job_1556742397967_0001
2019-05-01 22:27:42,890 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-05-01 22:27:43,048 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
2019-05-01 22:27:43,250 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1556742397967_0001
2019-05-01 22:27:43,254 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2019-05-01 22:27:43,543 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2019-05-01 22:27:43,544 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2019-05-01 22:27:44,093 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1556742397967_0001
2019-05-01 22:27:44,155 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://LAPTOP-PN52M98R:8088/proxy/application_1556742397967_0001/
2019-05-01 22:27:44,157 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1556742397967_0001
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have no active NodeManagers

```
Memory Total: 0B   VCores Total: 0
Unhealthy Nodes: 1
```

Your job was accepted by the ResourceManager, but cannot be ran until there are available resources to start it on

I suggest finding the NodeManager log file on your machine, then seeing if there are any noticable exceptions mentioned there